# How to uniquely identify monitor in Linux

Tags: linux, monitors, multi-monitor, edid

I am C++ application which will be binded to specific monitor. Currently I am using edid to identify monitor and disable certain features in the application.

This works if monitors are of different make and model. If I connect another monitor of same make and model, the edid received is same, hence application cannot detect the change of monitor.

Is there any other way to uniquely identify monitors in Linux?